# Ocultar o cerrar función void?

Tags: c++

tengo este código listo y cumple su función. El único detalle es que deseo ocultar o cerrar el "void anal ()" justo cuando se impriman los resultados. Es decir que cuando termine el "sleep" predeterminado para que se imprima un resultado necesito ocultar o eliminar el void anal "analizando", para que de la ilusión de un tiempo de análisis antes de sacar un resultado...
¿Cómo lo hago?

Lógica de programa: es una simulación de una maquina de análisis de sangre, seleccionas la muestra, tarda un poco en analizar y te muestra los resultados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int a, opcion;

void menu ();
void anal ();
 
main ()
{
    
    do{
        menu ();
        cout<< "\n \n De que paciente desea analizar la muestra?: "; cin>>opcion;sleep(0);
        anal();sleep(7);
        
        
        switch (opcion){
            
            case 1:  
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°  RESULTADOS  °°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Maria  Hernandez        °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 9         °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: O+ (O positivo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: hemoglobina Anormal°";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            
             case 2: cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°  RESULTADOS  °°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Ashly Gonzalez          °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 15        °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: A- (A negativo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: hemoglobina normal °";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            
            case 3:  cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°  RESULTADOS  °°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Yosman Leal             °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 20        °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: B+ (B positivo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: hemoglobina Anormal°";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            
            case 4:  cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°RESULTADOS°°°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Jose Martinez           °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 7         °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: B+ (B positivo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: hemoglobina Anormal°";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            
            case 5:  cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°  RESULTADOS  °°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Renzo Maldonado         °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 4         °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: O+ (O positivo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: Peligro hemoglobina°";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            
            case 6:  cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°  RESULTADOS  °°°°°°°°°°°";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° NOMBRE: Brayana Miere           °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Nivel de hemoglobina: 7         °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° Tipo de sangre: B+ (B positivo) °";
                     cout<<"\n\t ° OBSERVACION: hemoglobina Anormal°";
                     cout<<"\n\t °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\n";sleep(11);
            break;
            default: cout<<"\n\nESA MUESTRA NO EXISTE\n\n";
        } 
    }while(a!=10000);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void menu (){
        system("cls");
        cout<< "\n\t\t+-+-+-+-+-+ MAQUINA DE ANALISIS DE SANGRE +-+-+-+-+-+\n\n";
        cout<<"AVISO!!! PROMEDIO NORMAL DE HEMOGLOBINA: 15\n";
        cout<< "                                         --\n";
        cout<< "\n\t °°°°°°° MUESTRAS DISPONIBLES °°°°°°";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t1- Maria Hernandez         °";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t2- Ashly Gonzalez          °";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t3- Yosman Leal             °";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t4- Jose Martinez           °";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t5- Renzo Maldonado         °";
        cout<< "\n\t °\t6- Brayana Miere           °";
        cout<< "\n\t °_________________________________°\n";
}

void anal () {
    cout<<"\n\t% % % % ANALIZANDO MUESTRA % % % %\n";

}
```

Comment: Y que tal si usas una clase: class muestras{ proteted: void anal(){...} public: void all(){....}}; Desde afuera de la clase muestra no sera visible anal, pero si dentro de la clase.

Comment: Medicina. Buena materia, pero algo larga. Te deseo suerte.

Comment: No se usar muy bien poo aún, como implemento esa solución? ,son cosas básicas pero estoy aprendiendo:(

Comment: Si, creo que si. Aqui te dejo un enlaze que exprique sobre las clases:https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/50557/clases-y-objetos-en-c-practica-1#:~:text=Una%20clase%20puede%20pensarse%20como,que%20permiten%20manipular%20tales%20datos.